# Best way to print decimal number to maximum precision without trailing zeroes in Python

Tags: python, format, decimal, repr

Example to show my usecase:

```
from __future__ import division
a = 215 / 4
print a # Case 1. Should print 53.75

a = 215 / 3
print a # Case 2. Should print 71.6666666666666714 i.e. decimal to 16 precision.
```

Possible solutions which don't work:

```
print str(a) # Case 2 gets printed with only 12 precision (needed 16)

print repr(a) # Case 2 gets printed as 71.66666666666667 (precision 14, needed 16)

print '{0:.16f}'.format(a) # Case 1 gets printed with trailing zeroes

print '{0:.16g}'.format(a) # Decimal precision is 14, needed 16.
```

What would be the best pythonic solution to this?

**Edit:** If precision of 16 is a limitation of `float` division, what would be the pythonic way to get 8 decimals place precision. Is there a better soln. than `'{0:.8f}'.format(a).rstrip('0')`?

Comment: The precision is not actually 16 digits, because, as you can see, it ends in `714`, which is not correct.

Comment: Why do you want 16 digits displayed when floats don't actually have 16 digits of precision?

Comment: Does that mean it is not possible to get 18 significant digits (including precision of 16) with float division?

Comment: 18 significant digits is completely out of the question. The precision I'm talking about is the number of significant digits, and floats have slightly under 16 of those. If you need more significant digits, consider doing your calculations with [`decimal.Decimal`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html).

Comment: Ok. What if precision needed was inside the float limits, i.e., instead of 16, I wanted 8 decimal places precision result but with no trailing zeroes.

Comment: Maybe `rstrip` the zeros away?

Comment: No one has asked why? Why on earth do you need precision to the order of 10^-18?! Is your Python code going to be used to align crystal lattices or what?

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist Don't ask "why," ask "why not?". Maybe he wants to avoid floating point arithmetic errors after doing a few quadrillion operations on the FPU.

Comment: @mbomb007 And maybe it's premature optimization (or completely pointless) and we should give him (and future readers) the *correct* answer, rather than letting the OP lead us down the garden path?

Comment: No. In the spirit of programming, we do it because we can. It doesn't need to be practical. If he wants to discover how to do it, this is the place to ask.

Answer (score 1):

I believe getcontext() will be your friend here, in the decimal library.

This allows you to set precision and manipulate significant figure outcomes.

https://docs.python.org/2/library/decimal.html

Comment: This only applies to computations carried out with `decimal.Decimal`, and it doesn't really do anything for display precision.